# How to change phpmyadmin language to english?

Tags: 12.04, lamp, phpmyadmin

I have install LAMP in my Ubuntu 12.04 but the language of phpmyadmin is German instead of English. So I want to change this language to English. Please tell me the right procedure to change language.

Comment: May be a better fit for superuser.com

Comment: Your browser might be in German or configured to prefer websites in German.

Comment: How did you install phpMyAdmin? Using the upstream source or using the Ubuntu package? Can you select the language at the login screen? (I can using the Ubuntu package)

Answer (score 10):

on the first page of phpMyAdmin, you should have a dropdown list named `Sprache - Language` in which you will be able to select English.

If not, maybe your phpMyAdmin is not installed with all languages built-in, then you should re-install with Synaptic or APT...

Comment: Instead of using unsupported software from a third aprty's website, it is better to reinstall phpmyadmin package with synaptic or apt from terminal.

Comment: indeed. I don't have this habits regarding webapp, but you're right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: this does not save the language after log out

Answer (score 3):

It works for me as follows:

In config.inc.php, change value of Lang to en

```
$cfg['Lang'] = 'en';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert `$cfg['lang'] ='';` in  `wamp/bin/apps/phpmyadmin..../config.inc.php`.